# Passar parâmetro em formato json para consumir service post em app xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, android, rest, xamarin

No meu App tenho esse método para consumir o service post (ainda escrevendo o método):

```
public async Task<string> PostIndicador(string jsonValue)
{
    client = new HttpClient();
    string url = $"http://meu_ip/indicadorservice/indicadorservice.svc/metdodoservico";
    HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsonValue, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var uri = new Uri(string.Format(url));
    var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

    string responseMessage = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return responseMessage;
}
```

A pergunta é: Como eu passo o parâmetro em **formato json** para esse método? O parâmetro vem no argumento `jsonValue`.

Um esclarecimento apenas: Devo passar na URL o método que está no `Service(metdodoservico)`?

> P.S. Uma outra empresa desenvolveu o Service, logo não tenho acesso a
>   nada.

**EDIT1**

Minha model

```
public class TipoIndicador
    {
        public int IDUsuario { get; set; }
        public int IdTipoIndicador { get; set; }
        public decimal ValorPrevisto { get; set; }
        public decimal ValorRealizado { get; set; }
    }
    public class Indicador
    {
        public List<TipoIndicador> tipoIndicador { get; set; }
    }
```

**EDIT2**

```
public async Task<string> PostIndicador(string jsonValue)
        {            
            string url_base = $"meu_ip";
            var uri = new Uri(string.Format(url_base));
            using (var client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = uri })
            {
                var responeMessage =
                await client.PostAsync("/indicadorservice/indicadorservice.svc/metdodoservico", new StringContent("jsonValue", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
                var resultcontent = await responeMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resultcontent)).ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: A Json.net permite que você serialize seus objetos em json, algo como: `string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objeto);` e depois é só tu passar a variával 'data' no parâmetro da função. Se funcionar, posta a resposta aí! ;)

Comment: @itscorey, como eu monto o json que vou enviar para o serviço post? No SOAP UI eu passo assim: `{"iduser:1","idindicador:1"}` e como passo para o serviço? Não entendi bem o seu comentário.

Comment: E se esse método será de fato post, não esqueça de adicionar o [FromBody] e o ideal seria você construir uma model replicando o objeto json que você vai receber

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, é post sim e estou perdido em como proceder. Fiz uma model retornando os três campos que vem na request do serviço. Editei o post e coloquei lá a model.

Comment: @pnet, agora que eu vi que a sua questão é em enviar e não em receber

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, fiz uma alteração no código. Vou postar na nova edição. Só preciso saber como eu monto um json para enviar como parâmetro. Acho que foi isso que o colega itscovery quis dizer e não entendi naquele momento.